# Install ImageMagick for paperclip gem in a Mac OS 10.5.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unix, rubygems, imagemagick, paperclip

I have been trying to install ImageMagick for one week. The documentation I found over the net it is contradictory and I didn't find the proper way to install it and configure it. As well as I am not an UNIX expert so I don´t know how to use Enviroments paths correctly.

My software versions are:
S.O.: Mac OS 10.5.8, 
ImageMagick v6.7.7, 
Paperclip v3.1.2, 
Rails v3.0

Some hints:

The ~/.profile file:

```
export PATH=$HOME/Users/mac_name/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
export MAGICK_HOME="/Users/mac_name/ImageMagick-6.7.7"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$MAGICK_HOME/lib/
export DISPLAY=:0
```

I install ImageMagick with an installation script. Its located in: Users/mac_name/ImageMagick-6.7.7
Now I think it´s installed but paperclip it does not run. I still have the error: "Photo Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick".

```
$ echo $MAGICK_HOME
```

it returns: "/Users/mac_name/Users/mac_name/ImageMagick-6.7.7" (I don´t know why "Users/mac_name" it is repeated)

I need help. Any other gem that does not need ImageMagick? I am totally upset of this...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I will suggest you to install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and then install imagemagick using that.

To install Homebrew check [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew). Basically just copy paste this on your terminal:

```
 /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb)"
```

Now to install imagemagick run this command:

```
  brew install imagemagick
```

Lemme know if you face any issues.

Comment: I didn´t try this way because I have no usr/bin/ruby directory. It´s a problem if I create it manually?? or I have to install it in another folder?

Comment: which ruby -> /Users/mac_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby

Comment: Good luck :) Happy programing.

Comment: @MohitJain HI I am getting 404 error while executing the command https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb can you help me out

Answer (score 0):

Mohit has a great answer but the link seems broken now so checkout either 
[Homebrew Homepage at http://brew.sh](http://brew.sh)  or  [the Github page at https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew)

Both have good instructions on proper installation